# how sencha get string from records

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

here is my code. i want get "data" and "earn" string type from the records.

```
storeId.load({
        callback: function(records, operation, success){
            console.log(records);
            //Ext.getCmp('datalabel').setData({test: 'Foo'});                
        }
    });
```

in the chrome console:

```
0: Ext.apply.create.f
_data: Object    
data: Object
data: "300000"---------------i want
earn: "100000"---------------i want
id: "ext-record-2"
__proto__: Object
id: "ext-record-2"
internalId: "ext-record-2"
modified: Object
phantom: true
raw: Object
stores: Array[1]
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: I would suggest renaming the property of the model called data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the records or get a record by index:

```
storeId.load({
    callback: function(records, operation, success){
        Ext.each(records, function(record) {
            console.log(record.get('data'));
            console.log(record.get('earn'));
        });

        // or

        var recordByIndex = records[0];
        console.log(recordByIndex.get('data'));
        console.log(recordByIndex.get('earn'));
    }
});
```